# QT String to short int - Hex Value

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, short

I want to convert QString to short int. For eg,

Input:
QString str = "0x0001";
Output:
short int num = 0x0001;

I have tried toShort() method of QString but it converts "0x0024" to 24. But I want 0x0024 as the value. I know that short int can store value in the form of 0x.

Comment: Sorry for my last comment, that was stupid wrong. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toShort explains how to use `toShort` for different bases. How did you use it?

Comment: Without any argument.

Comment: There's the issue then. The second argument determines the base to use.

Comment: Tried toShort(&ok, 16). It returns the hex value. For eg. INPUT = "0x0024" OUTPUT= 36
I want my output to be 0x0024.

Comment: You dont want to convent to int. You want string representation of an int.  Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to use `toShort` or `toUInt`. However when using these functions, you have to give 10 instead of 16 to get the decimal value. For eg:

```
short hex = str.toUInt(&ok, 16); // returns 24
short dec = str.toUInt(&ok, 10); // returns 36
```

Comment: Set the base to 0 and enjoy the C convention: 0x00 for hex, 0b00 for bin, 0 for dec.